# How do I partition a MySQL table that contains several unique keys?

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

I have an extremely large MySQL table that I would like to partition. A simplified create of this table is as given  below -

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `columnA` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `columnB` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
  `columnC` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `columnD` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `columnE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `columnF` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `columnG` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_B` (`columnB`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_B_C` (`columnB`,`columnC`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_C_D` (`columnC`,`columnD`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_E_F_G` (`columnE`,`columnF`,`columnG`)
  )
```

I want to partition my table either by columnA or id, but the problem is that the MySQL Manual states -

> In other words, every unique key on the table must use every column in the table's partitioning expression.

Which means that I cannot partition the table on either of those columns without changing my schema. For example, I have considered adding `id` to all my unique keys like so -

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `columnA` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `columnB` varchar(50) NOT NULL ,
  `columnC` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `columnD` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `columnE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `columnF` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `columnG` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_B` (`columnB`,`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_B_C` (`columnB`,`columnC`,`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_C_D` (`columnC`,`columnD`,`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_E_F_G` (`columnE`,`columnF`,`columnG`,`id`)
  )
```

Which I do not mind doing except for the fact that it allows for the creation of rows that should not be created. For example, by my original schema, the following row insertion wouldn't have worked twice -

```
  INSERT into myTable (columnC, columnD) VALUES (1.0,2.0)
```

But it works with the second schema as columnC and columnD by themselves no longer form a unique key. I have considered getting around this by using triggers to prevent the creation of such rows but then the trigger cost would reduce(or outweigh) the partitioning performance gain

**Edited:**

Some additional information about this table:

1. Table has more than 1.2Billion records.
2. Using Mysql 5.6.34 version with InnoDB Engine and running on AWS RDS.
3. Few other indexes are also there on this table.
4. Because of huge data and multiple indexes it is an expensive process to insert and retrieve the data.
5. **There are no unique indexes on timestamp and float data types. It was just a sample table schema for illustration. Our actual table has similar schema as above table.**

> ***Other than Partitioning what options do we have to improve the
>   performance of the table without losing any data and maintaining the
>   integrity constraints.***

Comment: Why do you need all those keys?  Can you restructure your table to match the requirements needed for the partition to work?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Unfortunately I'm working with a table that is several years old and don't have that luxury

Comment: I upvoted your question, I hope that some MySQL guru will be able to help you.

Comment: Questions: 1. Does the column `(B)` in key declaration correspond to `ColumnB` (applies to all keys)? 2. You want to partition on `ID` or `ColumnA`, but `ColumnA` isnt indexed at all atm... is it truly unique and do you ever query the table on ColumnA? Is there something missing? 3. Since ID and ColumnA arent the same type, is your plan to define the partitionning type folowing the final choice? Can be either `BY KEY` or `BY DATE` here which changes a few things to the approach. Clear this up first ;-)

Comment: You cannot do this. MySQL creates subindexes for each partition. If it doesn't know which partition an entry is in, it would have to check every subindex to enforce uniqueness. (It could of course technically do this, but just doesn't). You can use workarounds like triggers (it depends on how much you change your data). But the more important thing is: There are only a handful of situation where partitioning improves performance (mostly in cases where it won't work anymore without). It will actually make most of your queries (except those using the primary key) slower because of ...

Comment: the overhead (of e.g. looking into several subindexes to lookup an entry). So you might want to check if you really need partitioning. The usual way to improve performance is to create an indexes (e.g. one that supports a specific slow query) - or to add more ram or a faster hdd/ssd to improve general server performance. Also, check your sample table definition - you have a unique key on `b`, and one on `b,c`, which is redundant (although it does not change your problem here).

Comment: @ThomasG My mistake about the unique keys, yes B does correspond to columnB. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Solarflare I agree that partitioning may not actual give me the performance gains that I am looking for. Will need to do a bit benchmarking. Still, fingers crossed for some brilliant answer

Comment: Timestamps in unique keys??  What if two events happen in the same second?  Floats in unique keys??  What if two values round to the same representation?  More than 2 unique keys??  Please provide some justification.  Partitioning?  What do you hope to gain; rarely do you get performance.

Comment: Please tell us the semantics; maybe we can unravel the _very unusual_ schema.

Comment: @RickJames The table that I had specified was for illustration purposes as I cannot mention the actual schema due to confidentiality reasons. However, I have edited my question so that the table is now a better representation of the actual schema.

Comment: _First_ I want to get rid of so many UNIQUE keys.  But I can't do that with "ColumnC".  I want to know what it represents.

Comment: @RickJames Like I said, I cannot give you the actual column title for confidentiality reason. The business logic which requires those UNIQUE keys is necessary. Although, at this point, if I do go through with partitioning, I am considering just removing all unique keys and enforcing those constraints in my code itself if no MySQL-only answer presents itself

Comment: If (B) is unique, then (B,C) is necessarily unique, and there is no need to declare it as such.  And there _may_ not be any advantage in even mentioning it as an `INDEX`.  When adding `id` onto the end (for partitioning) you _lose_ the uniqueness constraint for just (B).  So, again, you may as well make it an `INDEX`.

Comment: Which type of `PARTITION BY ...` are you thinking of using?  _Most_ variants are useless for performance.  _All_ invalidate `UNIQUE` constraints if you must add `id` on.  Do you really need `id`?  Maybe `PRIMARY KEY(B)` is viable?

Answer (score 3):

> How do I partition a MySQL table that contains several unique keys?

Sorry to say, you don't.

Also, you shouldn't. Remember that `UPDATE` and `INSERT` operations to a table with unique keys necessarily must query the table to ensure the keys stay unique. If it were possible to partition a table so unique keys weren't built in to the partititon expression, then *every* insert or update would require querying every partition. This would be likely to make the partitioning worse than useless.